# how to open a fragment with firebase dynamic link data?

Tags: java, android, firebase-dynamic-links, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I had a mainActivity with 4 fragments with drawer navigation.

1. start destination (Home page). It contains a recycler view with the list of items.
2. Detailed view destination (Detailed fragment). It is opened when the user clicks on any item on the start destination recycler view. It gets the data with **SafeArgs** and displays it.
3. some other destinations...

Now my problem is with the **Detailed View Destination.** Here I gave users an option to share. when user press share button, it gives a dynamic link.

When any user clicks on that dynamic link it opens my app MainActivity and also gets the required data from the server. **But how can I open that Detailed View fragment with this data in mainActivity?**
I'm using Jetpack NavigationUI to handle navigation in my app.

any one please help me...